# I have trouble with article

Tags: articles

I have just done an English exercise and it's about error correction: "You will remove one word which is unnecessary in each example."
 Here is the sentence which I meet the unnecessary word:

> Thanks to cheap air travel, for many people the world has grown significantly smaller over the last decade, but to vegetarians, the planet can still seem frustratingly limited. For millions of us who don't eat meat, getting the right food while on the holiday can be a key factor when choosing our destination.

The key told me that the unnecessary word is *the* but I don't know why? Could anyone explain it to me, please?

Comment: That's the wrong "the".  The extra "the" is the one before "holiday".

Comment: I see lots and lots of unnecessary words. Indeed, you can easily shorten the quote in half by throwing out everything that's not needed.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the unnecessary the:

"Thanks to cheap air travel, for many people the world has grown significantly smaller over the last decade, but to vegetarians, the planet can still seem frustratingly limited. For millions of us who don't eat meat, getting the right food while on **THE** holiday can be a key factor when choosing our destination."

Comment: Thank you so much !!